# Cómo saber si es o no la primera vez que inicia sesión un usuario

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js

Buenas estoy usando laravel 5.6 y Vue ,tengo un formulario en el cual doy de alta a usuarios, yo les asigno una contraseña la cuál quiero que cambien solo la primera ves que inician sesión.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

¿Has pensado en hacer una columna para ver el estado del usuario?

Es decir, "Activo", "Desactivado", "Pendiente"... Esta columna podría ser un [enum()](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/migrations#creating-columns) 
O una tabla nueva para poner distintas entradas y asociar la tabla con Usuario.

Cuando se crea un usuario se ponga en estado "Pendiente" y cuando confirma la contraseña que sea un usuario "Activo". Un usuario "Activo" ya no podrá cambiar de contraseña (Esa lógica debes programarla)

Comment: Vale una respuesta así buscaba a modo de lógica, muchas gracias lo haré con un booleano.